# Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error(React native)

Tags: react-native

I have installed the complete packages which are required for react native project. But after running the project i am getting this error i am not sure why.

I have also searched this issue on the internet but no luck.
[image]

Thanks
Amit

Comment: what does your terminal, where metro bundler is called, say?

Comment: Reboot your server or kill the sesione of node: "ps aux | grep node" select the correct Pid and kill it